# Forcing all sequential media hover thumbnails retrieved and cycled without having to hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying my hardest to figure out a way to get a grid of video thumbnails to animate without having to hover over each one individually. The thumbs for each animation aren't requested until hovering manually. Each video has an element like so:

```
<div class="favorite-video">
            <a href="/video/######">
                <img width="#" height="#" src="https://cdn.net/video/scr/#/#/#/#########################1_vthumb.jpg" class="image" alt="name">
                <span class="duration">##:##</span><em class="duration">##:##</em>

            </a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="i1">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="title"><a href="/video/######">name</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cycle-pic">
                        <a href="/video/######"><img width="#" height="#" src="https://cdn.net/video/scr/#/#/#/#########################1_vthumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="views"><i class="sho-views"></i>4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

once you hover, the thumbnail url goes through a 1-8 sequence where it changes the last number on the long hash thumb url to the next in the sequence. It retrieves all 8 images for the sequence once you hover, then it starts.

What I think corresponds to it is this function,

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    screenRotation: function(pause) {
        this.each(function(i, o) {
            var handler, cover, d, n, img, im = {};
            if (typeof pause == 'undefined') pause = 500;

            $(o).hover(function() {
                img = this;
                d = this.src.split('_');
                if (d.length != 2) return;

                cover = n = parseInt(d[0].charAt(d[0].length - 1));
                d[0] = d[0].substr(0, d[0].length - 1);

                for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) im[i] = (new Image).src = d[0] + i + '_' + d[1];

                handler = setInterval(function() {
                    n += 1;
                    if (n > 8) n = 1;
                    img.src = d[0] + n + '_' + d[1];
                }, pause);
            }, function() {
                if (this.src.split('_').length != 2) return;
                clearInterval(handler);
                this.src = d[0] + cover + '_' + d[1];
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I am wondering if I could just run a script to either simulate a hover on all thumbs on the page to get the 1-8 sequence images, then go from there. Or if it is even possible to do that without breaking other points in the function. I am not an expert, and I have done my best in trying to understand. Thank you, and please be kind to me.

Comment: You want to pre-download all images before the hover, is that it?

Comment: I want all of the videos to play the image sequence animations on the page at once, instead of having to hover each one and have it play only when hovered like it is now.  basically all animations always playing, and in that case the images would need to be fetched first. i think. thanks for reply sir.